# Automatically commit files in a folder in Windows?

Tags: windows, git

Is there a program which would automatically commit files into git when a file changes (or if that's problem, when it gets created)? There will be no conflicts as this folder will only be written by this user.

Under Linux inotify tools would let me do this but I am not familiar with Windows at all.

Comment: Define automatically. I'm guessing you mean periodic or if changed, or is there some other trigger?

Comment: Edited to make it more clear.

Comment: Have you checked Task Manager? It has GUI and command line options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using one of the many open-source Git auto-commit scripts like [git-autocommit](https://github.com/ralfholly/git-autocommit) or [gitwatch](https://github.com/gitwatch/gitwatch) along with a port of the [inotifywait tool for Windows](https://github.com/thekid/inotify-win) that is required to run these scripts.

Then you can watch a file or folder like that:

```
gitwatch.sh <file or directory to watch> [-p <remote> [-b <branch>]]
```